# YADR and Vim highlight color

Tags: vim

I have installed YADR for vim, https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles, and it messed up my Visual Block highlighting color. I have a black background, and my highlighting color is dark grey and I can't see what I am highlighting. Any help how to change the highlighting color?
I want to keep the background black.

Comment: So you have installed a large plugin distribution and you don't know how to tweak it? What about taking care of your own configuration yourself and… using a colorscheme that works for you?

Comment: I don't have time to configure each setting by myself. This is why I went with YADR, it is easy and does most of the time-wasting stuff for you.

Comment: Do you have a solution to my question that does not include criticism?

Comment: "does most of the time-wasting stuff for you" until you find something you don't like and, because of the very nature of YADR, you have no idea how to change it to your liking which leads to wasting time asking around for solution. Because not a lot of people use YADR or are familiar with it, you won't get the precise answers you'd get if you asked "Colorscheme x (link) does y (screenshot) and I don't like that. How can I make it do z?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run : 
`:verbose highlight` to see every highlight that has been modified and where.

You might refine it to `:verbose highlight Visual` to see the specific modifications for the visual selection.

Then try to comment out where it has been modified last and see what comes up when you retype the command.

You can either enforce a new default in your `.vimrc` or remove the plugin that is modifying it.